# How to change the entire Kubernetes cluster time zone

Tags: kubernetes, google-compute-engine

I have a running kubernetes cluster in GCE and currently it is having the default time zone UTC. Now I need to change the time zone for the entire cluster(Not for a single node or a pod). Please let me know How can I do that?

Comment: You can use DaemonSet to change timezone for all the GKE nodes. You can point the volume path of pods to specific timezone using the following example [https://evalle.xyz/posts/kubernetes-tz/]. Currently, we do not have a feature to change the timezone for the entire cluster on GKE end, you can create a Feature Request and provide your use case in this Public Issue Tracker [https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187077&template=0]

Comment: @Ariv the first link is dead.

Comment: @Jolta -- remove square bracket ( ] ) -- https://evalle.xyz/posts/kubernetes-tz/

Comment: @KrishnaGangaraju the link only deals with manually changing the time zone at the pod level to known fixed time zone. The question is specifically asking how to change the entire cluster's time zone and possibly to make pods accept the cluster timezone without needing to manually encode that timezone in all pods.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you will not be able to globally set the TimeZone (TZ) in a cluster.

You can find more detailed information about the reason in this response [How to change TimeZone of entire Kubernetes cluster?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59292609/15451744).

However the solutions that are offered in that post could be "temporary" when working with clusters in GCE that by default uses Container-Optimized OS.

Check this documentation [Using Container-Optimized OS](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/concepts/features-and-benefits#using_container-optimized_os):

> Container-Optimized OS is the default node OS Image in Kubernetes
> Engine and other Kubernetes deployments on Google Cloud Platform. See
> the Kubernetes Engine Quickstart for more information on using
> Container-Optimized OS with Kubernetes Engine.

Then lets see [Changing the time zone](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/how-to/create-configure-instance#changing_the_time_zone), keeping in mind that:

> Note that /etc is stateless, so the time zone will be reset to the
> default (UTC0) every reboot.

So, If you don't use an Ubuntu **Image Type** for your nodes (Container-Optimized OS is the default), you have nothing to do with time zone settings.

See [Available node images](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/node-images#available_node_images)to know the node images available for Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE) nodes.